# unable to connect to the internet through ethernet

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet, ethernet

My laptop (Lenovo G-50-80) was connecting fine to the internet through ethernet but I had to turn it off by long pressing the power button after it had frozen for over 10 minutes because the VMware Player had frozen up.

But after turning on my computer again, i am only able to use the internet through a wireless connection case in point asking this question.

Here is the output of some of the necessary configuration files and commands that I thought might help:

**`/etc/network/interfaces`**:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`**:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

**`/etc/resolv.conf`**:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search xxx.xx.xx
```

**`ip link`**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:7b:9d:12:a4:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:f8:9c:d7:9b:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I watched `syslog` file by running the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and here is the output...

**When connected to wireless:**

```
Apr 12 16:43:47 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:45:01 Lenovo-G50-80 CRON[4015]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr 12 16:46:05 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:46:16 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:46:26 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:46:36 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:51:03 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:51:13 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:51:23 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 12 16:51:33 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd-timesyncd[781]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

**When I tried to switch to ethernet:**

```
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2170] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Auto Ethernet' (308a058b-d505-4b7d-911f-06e133a924ec)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2172] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="308a058b-d505-4b7d-911f-06e133a924ec" name="Auto Ethernet" pid=1761 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2174] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2201] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2210] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2216] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2238] dhcp4 (enp2s0): dhclient started with pid 4231
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:enp2s0 index:2 flags:0x00011043
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:enp2s0 index:2 flags:0x00011043
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.18 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x269ab741)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: DHCPNAK from 10.103.0.56 (xid=0x41b79a26)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2634] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed unknown -> expire
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.2737] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed expire -> unknown
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x91220402)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.18 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2042291)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.18 from 192.168.0.1
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.18 from 192.168.0.1
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3716]   address 192.168.0.18
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3716]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3716]   gateway 192.168.0.1
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3716]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3716]   lease time 86400
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3716]   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3717] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWADDR: index:2, addr:192.168.0.18
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 avahi-daemon[903]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.18.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 avahi-daemon[903]: New relevant interface enp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 avahi-daemon[903]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.18 on enp2s0.IPv4.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWROUTE: index:2
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWROUTE: index:2
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3741] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnetBridge: Stopped bridge wlp3s0 to virtual network 0.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 vmnetBridge: Started bridge enp2s0 to virtual network 0.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3754] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873139] bridge-wlp3s0: disabling the bridge on dev down
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873175] bridge-wlp3s0: down
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873189] bridge-wlp3s0: detached
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873226] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2129 (vmnet-bridge)
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873236] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873273] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873285] bridge-enp2s0: up
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  878.873289] bridge-enp2s0: attached
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.3779] device (enp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.4416] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.4418] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.4420] policy: set 'Auto Ethernet' (enp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541125.4421] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 dhclient[4231]: bound to 192.168.0.18 -- renewal in 39410 seconds.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  879.071512] userif-3: sent link down event.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 kernel: [  879.071516] userif-3: sent link up event.
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1457]: ** (process:2337): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: Operation not supported by backend
Apr 12 16:52:05 Lenovo-G50-80 whoopsie[1957]: [16:52:05] offline
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1523541126.8824] device (enp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 dbus[933]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 whoopsie[1957]: [16:52:06] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 whoopsie[1957]: [16:52:06] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 whoopsie[1957]: [16:52:06] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 whoopsie[1957]: [16:52:06] online
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 dbus[933]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 12 16:52:06 Lenovo-G50-80 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 12 16:52:07 Lenovo-G50-80 avahi-daemon[903]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::ebba:fab2:4727:42aa.
Apr 12 16:52:07 Lenovo-G50-80 avahi-daemon[903]: New relevant interface enp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 12 16:52:07 Lenovo-G50-80 avahi-daemon[903]: Registering new address record for fe80::ebba:fab2:4727:42aa on enp2s0.*.
```

What could be the issue here and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What happens if you disable the vmnet/vfs/vmware?

Comment: @heynnema how do i do that

Comment: I'm not familiar with vmnet/vfs/vmware, but you'd probably start with something like `sudo systemctl stop vmnet`... or you might have to uninstall it. Also, do you have 2 routers in your network configuration?

Comment: @heynnema right now my vmware player is not running so when i run that command i get `Failed to stop vmnet.service: Unit vmnet.service not loaded.`, so i guess it's not the issue

Comment: That command may not be the exact command that you need to stop the vm* services. You'll have to research it a little yourself, as I'm not that familiar with vm*, but some of the error messages indicate that your problem might be related. Tell me more about your network config. Do you have two routers?

Comment: Am no networking expert but the brief knowledge i have is that both the wireless and ethernet networks use the same configurations for the dns and dhcp

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with dns/dhcp... but with the vm* and vfs software. You didn't describe your network config, and how many routers are installed.

Comment: Am really sorry i can't say for sure

Comment: Without knowing your network configuration, it may be difficult to help you fully resolve your problem. Keep us posted.